# Neo4j Jdbc connection pool

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

I am using JDBC driver for Neo4j in my jersey java web application for rest api.
The problem is that it takes a lot of time to open a jdbc Neo4j connection. For every rest api I am opening a neo4j connection and closing it after processing.

Which is the best connection pool I can use here in this scenario. After googling I found loads of connection pool apis for java. 
Which one do you recommend

Here are the neo4j jdbc drivers
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc#neo4j-jdbc-driver

Comment: How do you use it? When do you create a connection? You should keep the connection around and only create new statements.

Comment: I create a connection whenever a rest api request is done and close the connection when my request is completed.

Answer (score 1):

For the upcoming Neo4j Grails plugin I'm using [tomcat jdbc pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) since it seems to be the most frequently used one these days.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4J 3.0 recently released with a new [Java Driver](http://neo4j.com/developer/java/#neo4j-java-driver). I implemented it in one of my REST APIs by initialising the driver at the start of the application and then using it throughout the app to get sessions and run cypher queries on a remote database.

The performance seems to be better compared to the Neo4J JDBC driver.